# Confusion with Gibb's energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, reversibility

For a reversible process , I can show that $$\mathrm dG=0$$

For the same reversible process I can also prove that $$\mathrm dG=\mathrm dW_{\text{max, non } P-V\text{ work}}$$

Does that imply maximum non PV work that can be obtained from system is zero in reversible process but we know that maximum work is obtained during the reversible process?

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_free_energy) also states that

> The Gibbs free energy change $({\displaystyle \Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S})$, measured in joules in SI) is the maximum amount of non-expansion work that can be extracted from a closed system (one that can exchange heat and work with its surroundings, but not matter) at fixed temperature and pressure. This maximum can be attained only in a completely reversible process.

But change in Gibb's free energy for a reversible process is zero then how can maximum be attained in reversible process?

The article further states that

> When a system transforms reversibly from an initial state to a final state under these conditions, the decrease in Gibbs free energy equals the work done by the system to its surroundings, minus the work of the pressure forces.

But why will Gibb's energy decrease for reversible reaction, the change in it should be simply zero?

Can someone please clear up my consfusion?

Comment: Since when is delta G for a reversible process on a closed system equal to zero?

Comment: @ChetMiller at constant temperature and pressure,so?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gibbs free energy and maximum work](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138955/)

Comment: At **constant temperature** for a **closed system**, if you **allow only pressure–volume work** and then maintain a **constant pressure**, then no work can be extracted. You need to relax one of these four constraints for something interesting to happen.